# different date format in java after fetching from oracle

Tags: java, oracle, date, date-format

In my db `max date is as : 27-FEB-12`

when i am fetching data by java from db that is:

```
select to_char(max(CREATE_DT),'dd-mm-yyyy') from PROFILE_DETAILS;
```

gives me `2012-02-27 00:00:00.0`

How can i convert it to: `27-FEB-12`( i am trying to use indian date format)

Any idea please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why you need to_char function in your query. If you are fetching data by jdbc, oracle could give you  Date object. It is in your case much easier to convert into different format (String) in future.

anyway  based on your current requirement, with to_char, you get a String `2012-02-27 00:00:00.0`. now you want to get another string `27-FEB-12`. you could do something like below(exception handling was omitted):

```
final String s = "2012-02-27 00:00:00.0";
String newDateString = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy").format(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S").parse(s));
```

this will give you 27-Feb-12

Answer (score 1):

In an Oracle `DATE` column there is no format; the string representation you see when you `select max(create_dt)) from profile_details` in SQL*Plus, say, is using an implicit format mask from your NLS settings, which appears to be `DD-MON-RR` in that client.

You JDBC call is applying an explicit format mask, which is the right thing to do *if you want Java to treat it as a String*, not least because it may have different NLS settings. But your mask doesn't match what you say you want; you're specifying `DD-MM-YYYY` when you want `DD-MON-RR`.

But it also looks like you're probably retrieving the value from the JDBC call with a `getDate()` call, and it's being implicitly cast back to a Java Date object type. If you want to treat it as a Date in Java, then you don't need the `to_char` in your select, and you need to use Java tools (e.g. `SimpleDateFormat` as @Andrew Logvinov suggests) to turn it into a String as needed. If you're only ever treating it as a String - for immediate display, say - then use `getString()` instead, and fix your date format mask in the query.

**Edit**

If you retrieve the value from JDBC with `getDate()` and want to see the value as a String in the format you specified, you need to do something like:

```
Date raw_date;
String string_date;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
raw_date = <resultSet>.getDate(1);
string_date = sdf.format(raw_date);
```

Comment: thanks but by getDate()` i am getting 2012-02-27 but not 27-FEB-12

Answer (score 1):

```
        String strDate = "2012-02-27 00:00:00.0";
        String TimeZoneIds = TimeZone.getDefault().getID();


        SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S");
        SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        sdf2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(TimeZoneIds));

        try {
            Date date = sdf1.parse(strDate);
            String strFinalDate = sdf2.format(date);

            System.out.println(strFinalDate);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select to_char(max(CREATE_DT),'dd-MON-yy') from PROFILE_DETAILS;
```

Comment: This doesn't help if the value is retrieved with `getDate()`.

Comment: Correct. I just assumed it was retrieved using getString() as it's explicitly converted to text in the query (to_char).

Comment: The format he sees in Java doesn't match the existing `to_char` format mask, so I figured there must be another conversion somewhere, probably implicitly from retrieving it as a Date. Which makes the `to_char` pointless, as others have pointed out.